# How to use parse_url in my code

Tags: php

I have page asgym.pl. I have connected two plugins **Weglot** and **Dynamic-pricing-and-discounts-for-woocommerce**.

When someone clicked   "EN" button, language should changed to English  and currency will be changed to "GBP" but when some one clicked button "PL", Language will be change to polish and currency will be changed to "PLN".

the change in script  consists  od add to url value ="?wmc-currency=GBP" or "?wmc-currency=PLN", but when i change language more number of times, url changed from new value to old value.

How to change code to be old value will be destroyed and new value will be added to url.

```
{
    if ($d != $current) {
        $link = ($d != $this - > original_l) ? $this - > replaceUrl($this - > home_dir.$this - > request_uri_no_language, $d) : $this - > home_dir.$this - > request_uri_no_language;
        if ($link == $this - > home_dir.
            '/' && get_option('wg_auto_switch') == 'on') {

        }
        $value['en'] = 'wmc-currency=GBP';
        $value['pl'] = 'wmc-currency=PLN';


        $list. = '<li class="wg-li '.$flag_class.$d.
        '"> <
        a data - wg - notranslate href = "' . $link .'?'.$value[$d].'" > ' . ($withname ? ($full ? WGUtils::getLangNameFromCode( $d,false ) : strtoupper( $d )) : '
        ') . ' < /a></li > ';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very hard to read; you should post your code and describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: Something is wrong with the code, it's not valid anyways. Whole question is hart to read.